# HTML Multi step form doesn't work on Mobile

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a multistep form but the multi-steps doesn't work on mobile it shows all the steps in one go even the success message.

Please help me if possible

````
The HTML-CSS and javascript code I got it from here: 

 https://codepen.io/TyStelmach/pen/yNxMeJ


---

The HTML Code
```
<head>
    
    
    <meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
<!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
  integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

    
    
    
    
      <script src=
    "https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js">
  </script>

  <script src=
"https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"
    type="text/javascript">
  </script>
  


  <script src=
"https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js">
  </script>
 
           <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>  
           <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script> 
           
           
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-easing/1.3/jquery.easing.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.13.1/jquery.validate.js"></script>

</head>


<div class="info">
  <h1>Please fill in the form </h1>
  <span>
    Made with
    <i class="fa fa-beer"></i>
    by
    <a href="http://www.aaa-wa.com">AAA Web Agency</a>
    <div class="spoilers">
Need “Permission to Contact” language that is TCPA compliant    </div>
  </span>
</div>



<!-- Modal -info -->
<div class="container">
<div id="modal-3" class="modal" data-modal-effect="slide-top">
  <div class="modal-content">
    <h2 class="fs-title">Score Index</h2>
    <h3 class="fs-subtitle">Getting the most out of your data</h3>
    <p>Your data has been successfully submited</p>
    <input type="button" name="next" class="next action-button modal-close" value="Got it!">
  </div>
</div>
</div>
<form name='form1' class="steps" accept-charset="UTF-8" enctype="multipart/form-data" novalidate="">
  <ul id="progressbar">
    <li class="active">Step 1</li>
    <li>Step2</li>
    
  </ul>



  <!-- USER INFORMATION FIELD SET --> 
  <fieldset>
    <h2 class="fs-title">Basic Information</h2>
    <h3 class="fs-subtitle">We just need some basic information to begin</h3>
    <!-- Begin What's Your User ID Field -->
        
            <div class="hs_firstname field hs-form-field">

        
          <label for="firstname-99a6d115-5e68-4355-a7d0-529207feb0b3_2983">Your 8 digits User ID *</label>

          <input id="id" name="user_id"  required="required" type="number" onkeyup="GetDetail(this.value)" value="" placeholder="" data-rule-required="true" data-msg-required="Please insert your 8 digits User ID" >
          <span class="error1" style="display: none;">
              <i class="error-log fa fa-exclamation-triangle"></i>
          </span>
        </div>
        
    <!-- End What's Your User ID Field -->
    
    <!-- Begin What's Your First Name Field -->
        <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
          <label for="firstname-99a6d115-5e68-4355-a7d0-529207feb0b3_2983">What's your First Name? *</label>

          <input id="first_name" name="first_name" required="required" type="text" value="" placeholder="" data-rule-required="true" data-msg-required="Please include your first name" >
          <span class="error1" style="display: none;">
              <i class="error-log fa fa-exclamation-triangle"></i>
          </span>
        </div>
        
    <!-- End What's Your First Name Field -->
    
    
<!-- Begin What's Your Last Name Field -->
        <div class="col-md-6">
        
          <label for="firstname-99a6d115-5e68-4355-a7d0-529207feb0b3_2983">What's your First Name? *</label>

          <input id="last_name" name="last_name" required="required" type="text" value="" placeholder="" data-rule-required="true" data-msg-required="Please include your last name" >
          <span class="error1" style="display: none;">
              <i class="error-log fa fa-exclamation-triangle"></i>
          </span>
        </div>
        </div>
    <!-- End What's Your Last Name Field -->
    
    <!-- Begin Address Field -->
        <div class="hs_firstname field hs-form-field">
        
          <label for="firstname-99a6d115-5e68-4355-a7d0-529207feb0b3_2983">Your Address *</label>

          <input id="address" name="address" required="required" type="text" value="" placeholder="" data-rule-required="true" data-msg-required="Please include your address" >
          <span class="error1" style="display: none;">
              <i class="error-log fa fa-exclamation-triangle"></i>
          </span>
        </div>
    <!-- End Adress Field -->
    <!-- Begin City Field -->
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
        
          <label for="firstname-99a6d115-5e68-4355-a7d0-529207feb0b3_2983">City *</label>

          <input id="city" name="city" required="required" type="text" value="" placeholder="" data-rule-required="true" data-msg-required="Please include your City" >
          <span class="error1" style="display: none;">
              <i class="error-log fa fa-exclamation-triangle"></i>
          </span>
        </div>
    <!-- End City Field -->
    <!-- Begin State Field -->
        <div class="col-md-4">
        
          <label for="firstname-99a6d115-5e68-4355-a7d0-529207feb0b3_2983">State *</label>

          <input id="state" name="state" required="required" type="text" value="" placeholder="" data-rule-required="true" data-msg-required="Please include your State" >
          <span class="error1" style="display: none;">
              <i class="error-log fa fa-exclamation-triangle"></i>
          </span>
        </div>
    <!-- End State Field -->
    <!-- Begin Zip Field -->
        <div class="col-md-4">
        
          <label for="firstname-99a6d115-5e68-4355-a7d0-529207feb0b3_2983">Zip Code *</label>

          <input id="zip" name="zip" required="required" type="text" value="" placeholder="" data-rule-required="true" data-msg-required="Please include your Zip Code" >
          <span class="error1" style="display: none;">
              <i class="error-log fa fa-exclamation-triangle"></i>
          </span>
        </div>
        </div>
    <!-- End Zip Field -->
   
    
    <!-- Begin What's Your Email Field -->
        <div class="hs_email field hs-form-field">
        
          <label for="email-99a6d115-5e68-4355-a7d0-529207feb0b3_2983">Your E-mail Address? *</label>

          <input id="email-99a6d115-5e68-4355-a7d0-529207feb0b3_2983" name="email" required="required" type="email" value="" placeholder="" data-rule-required="true" data-msg-required="Please enter a valid email address." >
          <span class="error1" style="display: none;">
              <i class="error-log fa fa-exclamation-triangle"></i>
          </span>
        </div>
    <!-- End What's Your Email Field -->

   


    <!-- Begin Total Number of Constituents in Your Database Field -->
        <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
        
          <label for="edit-submitted-constituent-base-total-constituents total_number_of_constituents_in_your_database-99a6d115-5e68-4355-a7d0-529207feb0b3_6344">Cell Phone No. *</label>

          <input id="cell" class="form-text hs-input" name="cell" required="required" size="60" maxlength="128" type="phone" value="" placeholder="" data-rule-required="true" data-msg-required="Please enter a valid Cell Phone Number" >
          <span class="error1" style="display: none;">
              <i class="error-log fa fa-exclamation-triangle"></i>
          </span>
        </div>
         

    <!-- End Cell Phone Field -->
    <!-- Begin Total Number of Constituents in Your Database Field -->
        <div class="col-md-4">
        
          <label for="edit-submitted-constituent-base-total-constituents total_number_of_constituents_in_your_database-99a6d115-5e68-4355-a7d0-529207feb0b3_6344">Office Phone No. </label>

          <input id="office_phone" class="form-text hs-input" name="office_phone" required="required" size="60" maxlength="128" type="phone" value="" placeholder="" data-rule-required="false" data-msg-required="Please enter a Office Phone Number" >
          <span class="error1" style="display: none;">
              <i class="error-log fa fa-exclamation-triangle"></i>
          </span>
        </div>

    <!-- End Cell Phone Field -->


     <!-- Begin Office Phone Field -->
        
        <div class="col-md-4">
        
          <label for="edit-submitted-constituent-base-total-constituents total_number_of_constituents_in_your_database-99a6d115-5e68-4355-a7d0-529207feb0b3_6344">Home Phone No.</label>

          <input id="home_phone" class="form-text hs-input" name="home_phone" required="required" size="60" maxlength="128" type="phone" value="" placeholder="" data-rule-required="false" data-msg-required="Please enter a valid number" >
          <span class="error1" style="display: none;">
              <i class="error-log fa fa-exclamation-triangle"></i>
          </span>
        </div>
        </div>
      <!-- End Office Phone Field -->

<input type="button" data-page="1" name="next" class="next action-button" value="Next" />
    
  </fieldset>



 
  






  <!-- RETENTION FIELD SET -->  
  <fieldset>
    <h2 class="fs-title">Retention of your donors</h2>
    <h3 class="fs-subtitle">How long can you keep your donors and their donations?</h3>
        <!-- Begin Monthly Rent Field -->
          <div class="form-item webform-component webform-component-textfield hs_number_of_donors_in_year_1 field hs-form-field" id="webform-component-retention--amount-1"> 
        
          <label for=" edit-submitted-retention-amount-1 number_of_donors_in_year_1-99a6d115-5e68-4355-a7d0-529207feb0b3_2983">Monthly Rent</label>

          <input id="monthly_rent" class="form-text hs-input" name="monthly_rent" required="required" size="60" maxlength="128" type="text" value="" placeholder="" data-rule-required="false" data-msg-required="Please enter a valid Monthly Rent">
          <span class="error1" style="display: none;">
              <i class="error-log fa fa-exclamation-triangle"></i>
          </span>
          </div>
        <!-- End Monthly Rent Field-->
        <!-- Begin Length of time at residence? Field -->
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-6" id="webform-component-retention--amount-1"> 
        
          <label for=" edit-submitted-retention-amount-1 number_of_donors_in_year_1-99a6d115-5e68-4355-a7d0-529207feb0b3_2983">Length of time at residence? __ yrs.</label>

          <input id="residence_yrs" class="form-text hs-input" name="residence_yrs" required="required" size="60" maxlength="128" type="text" value="" placeholder="" data-rule-required="false" data-msg-required="Please enter a valid Monthly Rent">
          <span class="error1" style="display: none;">
              <i class="error-log fa fa-exclamation-triangle"></i>
          </span>
          </div>
        <!-- End Length of time Field-->
        <!-- Begin Length of time at residence? Field -->
          <div class="col-md-6" id="webform-component-retention--amount-1"> 
        
          <label for=" edit-submitted-retention-amount-1 number_of_donors_in_year_1-99a6d115-5e68-4355-a7d0-529207feb0b3_2983">Length of time at residence?___ mos.</label>
          <input id="residence_mos" class="form-text hs-input" name="residence_mos" required="required" size="60" maxlength="128" type="text" value="" placeholder="" data-rule-required="false" data-msg-required="Please enter a valid Monthly Rent">
          <span class="error1" style="display: none;">
              <i class="error-log fa fa-exclamation-triangle"></i>
          </span>
          </div>
          </div>
        <!-- End Length of time mons Field-->
                <!-- Begin Age Field -->
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-6" id="webform-component-retention--amount-1"> 
        
          <label for=" edit-submitted-retention-amount-1 number_of_donors_in_year_1-99a6d115-5e68-4355-a7d0-529207feb0b3_2983">Age</label>

          <input id="age" class="form-text hs-input" name="age" required="required" size="60" maxlength="128" type="text" value="" placeholder="" data-rule-required="false" data-msg-required="Please enter a valid Age">
          <span class="error1" style="display: none;">
              <i class="error-log fa fa-exclamation-triangle"></i>
          </span>
          </div>
        <!-- End Age Field-->
        <!-- Begin Gender Field -->
          <div class="col-md-6" id="webform-component-retention--amount-1"> 
        
          <label for=" edit-submitted-retention-amount-1 number_of_donors_in_year_1-99a6d115-5e68-4355-a7d0-529207feb0b3_2983">Gender</label>
          <input id="gender" class="form-text hs-input" name="gender" required="required" size="60" maxlength="128" type="text" value="" placeholder="" data-rule-required="false" data-msg-required="Please enter a valid Monthly Rent">
          <span class="error1" style="display: none;">
              <i class="error-log fa fa-exclamation-triangle"></i>
          </span>
          </div>
          </div>
        <!-- End Gender Field-->
        
                <!-- Begin Length of time at residence? Field -->
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-6" id="webform-component-retention--amount-1"> 
        
          <label for=" edit-submitted-retention-amount-1 number_of_donors_in_year_1-99a6d115-5e68-4355-a7d0-529207feb0b3_2983">Spouse’s Name</label>

          <input id="spouse_name" class="form-text hs-input" name="spouse_name" required="required" size="60" maxlength="128" type="text" value="" placeholder="" data-rule-required="false" data-msg-required="Please enter a valid Spouse’s Name">
          <span class="error1" style="display: none;">
              <i class="error-log fa fa-exclamation-triangle"></i>
          </span>
          </div>
        <!-- End Spouse’s Name Field-->
        <!-- Begin Spouse’s Age Field -->
          <div class="col-md-6" id="webform-component-retention--amount-1"> 
        
          <label for=" edit-submitted-retention-amount-1 number_of_donors_in_year_1-99a6d115-5e68-4355-a7d0-529207feb0b3_2983">Spouse’s Age</label>
          <input id="spouse_age" class="form-text hs-input" name="spouse_age" required="required" size="60" maxlength="128" type="text" value="" placeholder="" data-rule-required="false" data-msg-required="Please enter a valid Spouse’s Age">
          <span class="error1" style="display: none;">
              <i class="error-log fa fa-exclamation-triangle"></i>
          </span>
          </div>
          </div>
        <!-- End Spouse’s Age Field-->

       

        <!-- Begin Have you contributed to a 401(k)/403(b)/IRA retirement program in the past year? select -->
          <div class="form-item webform-component webform-component-textfield" id="webform-component-retention--percent-change field hs-form-field">
        
          <label for="edit-submitted-retention-percent-change">Retention Rate</label>

         <select id="select1" class="form-text hs-input" name="select1"  value="" placeholder="0">
             <option value="yes">Yes</option>
             <option value="no">No</option>

          </select>

          <span class="error1" style="display: none;">
              <i class="error-log fa fa-exclamation-triangle"></i>
          </span>
          </div>

        <!-- End Have you contributed to a 401(k)/403(b)/IRA retirement program in the past year? select -->
        <!-- Begin Best time/day to contact Field -->
          <div class="form-item webform-component webform-component-textfield hs_number_of_donors_in_year_1 field hs-form-field" id="webform-component-retention--amount-1"> 
        
          <label for=" edit-submitted-retention-amount-1 number_of_donors_in_year_1-99a6d115-5e68-4355-a7d0-529207feb0b3_2983">Best time/day to contact:</label>

          <input id="best_time" class="form-text hs-input" name="best_time" required="required" size="60" maxlength="128" type="text" value="" placeholder="" data-rule-required="false" data-msg-required="Please enter a valid time">
          <span class="error1" style="display: none;">
              <i class="error-log fa fa-exclamation-triangle"></i>
          </span>
          </div>
        <!-- End Best time/day to contact Field-->


       
    <input type="button" data-page="5" name="previous" class="previous action-button" value="Previous" />
    <input id="submit" class="hs-button primary large action-button next" type="submit" value="Submit">
    <div class="explanation btn btn-small modal-trigger" data-modal-id="modal-3">What Is This?</div>
</fieldset>

  <fieldset>
    <h2 class="fs-title">It's on the way!</h2>
    <h3 class="fs-subtitle">Thank you for trying out our marketing grader, please go check your email for your fundraising report card and some helpful tips to improve it!</h3>
    <div class="explanation btn btn-small modal-trigger" data-modal-id="modal-3">What Is This?</div>
  </fieldset>
  
 ```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a media query in your CSS that is responsible for exactly that behavior.

```
@media (max-width:675px){
/*mobile phone: uncollapse all fields: remove progress bar*/

.steps {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 50px auto;
  position: relative;
}

#progressbar{
  display:none;
}

/*move error logs */
.error1 {
  position: relative;
  left: 0 !important;
  margin-top: 24px;
  top: -11px;
}

.error1:before {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  left: 14px;
  top: -14px;
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  border-left: 6px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 8px solid #e62163;
  border-right: 6px solid transparent;
  }

/*show hidden fieldsets */
.steps fieldset:not(:first-of-type) {
  display: block;
}

.steps fieldset{
  position:relative;
  width: 100%;
  margin:0 auto;
  margin-top: 45px;
}

.steps .next, .steps .previous{
  display:none;
}

.steps .explanation{
  display:none;
}

.steps .submit {
  float: right;
  margin: 28px auto 10px;
  width: 100% !important;
}

}
```

Comment: very easy to discover if you make use of your developer tools, both Chrome and Firefox have a responsive design mode where you can simulate the resolution of any mobile device. If you drag the view port area in that mode you should see if at some specific break point elements disappear or change behavior.

Answer (score 0):

And the CSS code

```
/*basic reset*/
* {margin: 0; padding: 0;}

html {
 height: 100%;
 /*Image only BG fallback*/
 background: #e9e9e9;
}

body {
 font-family: montserrat, arial, verdana;
   width: 100%;
 overflow-x: hidden;
}
/*form styles*/
.steps {
   width: 100%;
 margin: 50px auto;
 position: relative;
}

.steps fieldset {
 background: white;
 border: 0 none;
 border-radius: 3px;
 box-shadow: 0 17px 41px -21px rgb(0, 0, 0);
 padding: 20px 30px;
 border-top: 9px solid #303030;
 box-sizing: border-box;
 width: 80%;
 margin: 0 10%;
 
 /*stacking fieldsets above each other*/
 position: relative;
}
/*Hide all except first fieldset*/
.steps fieldset:not(:first-of-type) {
 display: none;
}
/*inputs*/
.steps label{
 color: #333333;
 text-align: left !important;
 font-size: 15px;
 font-weight: 200;
 padding-bottom: 7px;
 padding-top: 12px;
 display: inline-block;
}


.steps input, .steps textarea {
 outline: none;
 display: block;
 width: 100%;
 margin: 0 0 20px;
 padding: 10px 15px;
 border: 1px solid #d9d9d9;
 -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
 -moz-border-radius: 3px;
 border-radius: 3px;
 color: #837E7E;
 font-family: "Roboto";
 -webkti-box-sizing: border-box;
 -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
 box-sizing: border-box;
 font-size: 14px;
 font-wieght: 400;
 -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
 -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
 -webkit-transition: all 0.3s linear 0s;
 -moz-transition: all 0.3s linear 0s;
 -ms-transition: all 0.3s linear 0s;
 -o-transition: all 0.3s linear 0s;
 transition: all 0.3s linear 0s;
}

.steps input:focus, .steps textarea:focus{
 color: #333333;
 border: 1px solid #303030;
}

.error1{
  -moz-border-radius: 3px;
 -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
 border-radius: 3px;
 -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 0 transparent;
 -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 0 transparent;
 box-shadow: 0 0 0 transparent;
 position: absolute;
 left: 105px;
 margin-top: -58px;
 padding: 0 10px;
 height: 39px;
 display: block;
 color: #ffffff;
 background: #e62163;
 border: 0;
 font: 14px Corbel, "Lucida Grande", "Lucida Sans Unicode", "Lucida Sans", "DejaVu Sans", "Bitstream Vera Sans", "Liberation Sans", Verdana, "Verdana Ref", sans-serif;
 line-height: 39px;
 white-space: nowrap;

}

.error1:before{
   width: 0;
 height: 0;
 left: -8px;
 top: 14px;
 content: '';
 position: absolute;
 border-top: 6px solid transparent;
 border-right: 8px solid #e62163;
 border-bottom: 6px solid transparent;
}

.error-log{
   margin: 5px 5px 5px 0;
 font-size: 19px;
 position: relative;
 bottom: -2px;
}

.question-log {
 margin: 5px 1px 5px 0;
 font-size: 15px;
 position: relative;
 bottom: -2px;
 }

/*buttons*/
.steps .action-button, .action-button {
 width: 100px !important;
 background: #303030;
 font-weight: bold;
 color: white;
 border: 0 none;
 border-radius: 1px;
 cursor: pointer;
 padding: 10px 5px;
 margin: 10px auto;
 -webkit-transition: all 0.3s linear 0s;
 -moz-transition: all 0.3s linear 0s;
 -ms-transition: all 0.3s linear 0s;
 -o-transition: all 0.3s linear 0s;
 transition: all 0.3s linear 0s;
 display: block;
}

.steps .next, .steps .submit{
   float: right;
}

.steps .previous{
 float:left;
}

.steps .action-button:hover, .steps .action-button:focus, .action-button:hover, .action-button:focus {
 background:#444343;;
}

.steps .explanation{
display: block;
 clear: both;
 width: 540px;
 background: #f2f2f2;
 position: relative;
 margin-left: -30px;
 padding: 22px 0px;
 margin-bottom: -10px;
 border-bottom-left-radius: 3px;
 border-bottom-right-radius: 3px;
 top: 10px;
 text-align: center;
 color: #333333;
 font-size: 12px;
 font-weight: 200;
 cursor:pointer;
}


/*headings*/
.fs-title {
 text-transform: uppercase;
    margin: 0 0 5px;
    line-height: 1;
    color: #303030;
    font-size: 18px;
   font-weight: 400;
   text-align:center;
}
.fs-subtitle {
 font-weight: normal;
 font-size: 13px;
 color: #837E7E;
 margin-bottom: 20px;
 text-align: center;
}
/*progressbar*/
#progressbar {
 margin-bottom: 30px;
 overflow: hidden;
 /*CSS counters to number the steps*/
 counter-reset: step;
 width:100%;
 text-align: center;
}
#progressbar li {
 list-style-type: none;
   color: rgb(51, 51, 51);
 text-transform: uppercase;
 font-size: 9px;
 width: 50%;
 float: left;
 position: relative;
}
#progressbar li:before {
 content: counter(step);
 counter-increment: step;
 width: 20px;
 line-height: 20px;
 display: block;
 font-size: 10px;
 color: #333;
 background: white;
 border-radius: 3px;
 margin: 0 auto 5px auto;
}
/*progressbar connectors*/
#progressbar li:after {
 content: '';
 width: 100%;
 height: 2px;
 background: white;
 position: absolute;
 left: -50%;
 top: 9px;
 z-index: -1; /*put it behind the numbers*/
}
#progressbar li:first-child:after {
 /*connector not needed before the first step*/
 content: none; 
}
/*marking active/completed steps green*/
/*The number of the step and the connector before it = green*/
#progressbar li.active:before,  #progressbar li.active:after{
 background: #303030;
 color: white;
}


/* my modal */

.modal p{
 font-size: 15px;
 font-weight: 100;
 font-family: sans-serif;
 color: #3C3B3B;
 line-height: 21px;
}

.modal {
 position: fixed;
 top: 50%;
 left: 50%;
 width: 50%;
 max-width: 630px;
 min-width: 320px;
 height: auto;
 z-index: 2000;
 visibility: hidden;
 -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
 -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
 backface-visibility: hidden;
 -moz-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
 -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
 -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
 transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
.modal.modal-show {
 visibility: visible;
}
.lt-ie9 .modal {
 top: 0;
 margin-left: -315px;
}

.modal-content {
 background: #ffffff;
 position: relative;
 margin: 0 auto;
 padding: 40px;
 border-radius: 3px;
}

.modal-overlay {
 background: #000000;
 position: fixed;
 visibility: hidden;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 z-index: 1000;
 filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0);
 opacity: 0;
 -moz-transition-property: visibility, opacity;
 -o-transition-property: visibility, opacity;
 -webkit-transition-property: visibility, opacity;
 transition-property: visibility, opacity;
 -moz-transition-delay: 0.5s, 0.1s;
 -o-transition-delay: 0.5s, 0.1s;
 -webkit-transition-delay: 0.5s, 0.1s;
 transition-delay: 0.5s, 0.1s;
 -moz-transition-duration: 0, 0.5s;
 -o-transition-duration: 0, 0.5s;
 -webkit-transition-duration: 0, 0.5s;
 transition-duration: 0, 0.5s;
}
.modal-show .modal-overlay {
 visibility: visible;
 filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=60);
 opacity: 0.6;
 -moz-transition: opacity 0.5s;
 -o-transition: opacity 0.5s;
 -webkit-transition: opacity 0.5s;
 transition: opacity 0.5s;
}

/*slide*/
.modal[data-modal-effect|=slide] .modal-content {
 filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0);
 opacity: 0;
 -moz-transition: all 0.5s 0;
 -o-transition: all 0.5s 0;
 -webkit-transition: all 0.5s 0;
 transition: all 0.5s 0;
}
.modal[data-modal-effect|=slide].modal-show .modal-content {
 filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(enabled=false);
 opacity: 1;
 -moz-transition: all 0.5s 0.1s;
 -o-transition: all 0.5s 0.1s;
 -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
 -webkit-transition-delay: 0.1s;
 transition: all 0.5s 0.1s;
}
.modal[data-modal-effect=slide-top] .modal-content {
 -moz-transform: translateY(-300%);
 -ms-transform: translateY(-300%);
 -webkit-transform: translateY(-300%);
 transform: translateY(-300%);
}
.modal[data-modal-effect=slide-top].modal-show .modal-content {
 -moz-transform: translateY(0);
 -ms-transform: translateY(0);
 -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
 transform: translateY(0);
}


/* RESPONSIVE */

/* moves error logs in tablet/smaller screens */

@media (max-width:1000px){

/*brings inputs down in size */
.steps input, .steps textarea {
 outline: none;
 display: block;
 width: 100% !important;
 }

 /*brings errors in */
 .error1 {
 left: 345px;
 margin-top: -58px;
}




}


@media (max-width:675px){
/*mobile phone: uncollapse all fields: remove progress bar*/

.steps {
 width: 100%;
 margin: 50px auto;
 position: relative;
}

#progressbar{
 display:none;
}

/*move error logs */
.error1 {
 position: relative;
 left: 0 !important;
 margin-top: 24px;
 top: -11px;
}

.error1:before {
 width: 0;
 height: 0;
 left: 14px;
 top: -14px;
 content: '';
 position: absolute;
 border-left: 6px solid transparent;
 border-bottom: 8px solid #e62163;
 border-right: 6px solid transparent;
 }

/*show hidden fieldsets */
.steps fieldset:not(:first-of-type) {
 display: block;
}

.steps fieldset{
 position:relative;
 width: 100%;
 margin:0 auto;
 margin-top: 45px;
}

.steps .next, .steps .previous{
 display:none;
}

.steps .explanation{
 display:none;
}

.steps .submit {
 float: right;
 margin: 28px auto 10px;
 width: 100% !important;
}

}



/* Info */
.info {
 width: 300px;
 margin: 35px auto;
 text-align: center;
 font-family: 'roboto', sans-serif;
}

.info h1 {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 font-size: 28px;
 font-weight: 400;
 color: #333333;
 padding-bottom: 5px;

}
.info span {
 color:#666666;
 font-size: 13px;
 margin-top:20px;
}
.info span a {
 color: #666666;
 text-decoration: none;
}
.info span .fa {
 color: rgb(226, 168, 16);
 font-size: 19px;
 position: relative;
 left: -2px;
}

.info span .spoilers {
 color: #999999;
 margin-top: 5px;
 font-size: 10px;
}
```

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.